# Promise does not resolve to true or false

Tags: javascript, promise

```
export const checkLoggedIn = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    apiConfig.fetchApi('/users/is_valid', {}, 'get', {})
    .then((resp)=> {
        resolve(true);
    })
    .catch((exception)=> {
        reject(false);
    })
    .done()
  })
}
```

Above is my user token checking code.
But function `checkLoggedIn()` is giving like the below image
[image]

But I want to get true or false only.
Please if you find the issue in code, comment it out

Comment: just return the result of fetchApi and ur done

Comment: Wrapping an existing promise inside another promise is considered a [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) as it is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 3):

Please check the definitions of [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and [catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) and the general definition and usage of a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

It seems that in your example `apiConfig.fetchApi` returns a Promise (because you're using `then()` which works on a Promise). Thus you don't have to create a new Promise.

Your code could look like this (I excluded the response parameter here because you don't use it in your code snippet):

```
export const checkLoggedIn = () => (
  apiConfig.fetchApi('/users/is_valid', {}, 'get', {})
    .then(() => true)
    .catch(error => { console.log(error); return false; })
);
```

If `apiConfig.fetchApi` does **not** return a Promise, you can create a Promise. But then you have to work with the return value of `apiConfig.fetchApi` and resolve or reject depending on its value.

Comment: That `catch` callback will never execute.

Comment: Of course it could. Promise rejection is handled with `then`, but in case there's any error (network, invalid url, etc.) an error might be thrown and catched with `catch`.

Comment: An error *is* a rejection? It will be handled by the second `then` argument before ever reaching the `catch`, and none of your `then` callbacks can throw.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, sorry.. I got a bit confused right now.. You're right. Any thrown error should lead to a Promise rejection which would be catched with my `then()` call. I'll remove the reject part from `then`, so that my code is closer to the question.